# algorithm detected loop N-time

Tags: algorithm, loops

the algorithm for summing the salaries of N employees presented in the text performs a loop that consists  of adding one salary to the total and advancing a pointer on the employee list N-1 times. the last salary is added separately. what is reason for visit? why dont we perform the loop N times?

Comment: Hmm, performing `N` loops is better than  `N-1` with "last salary is added separately" as it handles the case of `N==0` with less complications.

Comment: I don't understand if it's categorized in employees who earn salaries

Comment: "algorithm ... presented in the text " --> better to post that text than only describe it.